# How to statically link PROJ to pybind11

Tags: cmake, pybind11, proj

I'm interested in statically linking PROJ to a library created with pybind11.
but, I get error by cmake.

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

My CMakeLists.txt is this.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(myearth LANGUAGES CXX)

add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(myearth MyEarth.cpp)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/PROJ/include)
add_library(proj4 STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(proj4 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/PROJ/lib/libproj.a)

target_link_libraries(myearth PRIVATE proj4)
```

CMake Error.
I think fPIC option is for shared library. so, libproj.a is not necessary this option because this is static library.

```
(venv) ~/Projects/LinkLibTest/MySample/build$ make
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/myearth.dir/MyEarth.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared module myearth.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/bin/ld: ../PROJ/lib/libproj.a(proj_4D_api.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `pj_errno' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/myearth.dir/build.make:98: myearth.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:100: CMakeFiles/myearth.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
(venv) ~/Projects/LinkLibTest/MySample/build$
```

I created libproj.a by the following command.

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/output --disable-shared
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
```

[image]

- Linux Mint 20.3 64bit
- CMake v3.22.2
- PROJ v5.2.0 (https://proj.org/)
- Python v3.6.8

Thank you.

Comment: Shared libraries must have position independent code, but your version of PROJ was built _without_ it; you will have to rebuild PROJ

Comment: Does this mean to use something other than version 5.2.0 of PROJ?  For example, latest. Or, should i add files or cmake commands when rebuilding version 5.2.0 of PROJ?

Comment: You will need to add `-fPIC` to PROJ's build. Check their documentation for how to do that

Comment: I succeeded with the command "./configure --prefix=/output --with-pic". I'll mark it if you post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared libraries must have position independent code, but your version of PROJ was built without it; you will have to rebuild PROJ with PIC.

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/output --with-pic
```